# adding harmonics on top each other ipython

Tags: python, ipython

I want the next sound heard to be a combination of all previous harmonics played simultaneously, but i cant get it to work. Still new to ipython so still learning how to use it.

```
t = arange(0, 0.5, 1/44100)
fundamental = 440
mySound = sin(2*pi*t*100)
for k in range(1,6) :
    print "Adding harmonic: ", k 
    mySound = concatenate([mySound,  (mySound+(sin(2*pi*((2*k)-1)*t*100)/((2*k)-1)))/k])
play(mySound)
plot(mySound[1:1000]) # plot first 1000 samples
```

Comment: Please add your imports and tag your question appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **addition, not concatenation**.  That is, something like:

```
for k in range(1,6) :
    print "Adding harmonic: ", k 
    mySound += sin(2*pi*((2*k)-1)*t*100)/((2*k)-1)))/k
    # or mySound = mySound + sin(2*pi*((2*k)-1)*t*100)/((2*k)-1)))/k  # is close to the same thing (though less efficient) and more similar to what you had
```

Concatenation would put the waveforms end-to-end, so you would hear them one after another, in sequence.